# vuejs failed to compile paypal is not defined while using paypal sdk / paypal checkout

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, paypal, checkout

I have the following problem while integerating paypal sdk in my vuejs project

```
 55:5  error  'paypal' is not defined  no-undef
```

index.html

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb"></script>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Checkout.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="checkout"></div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0.01
    }
  },

  mounted: function(){
    paypal.Buttons().render('.checkout')
  }
}
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is, to render paypal buttons each time, the view is loaded. It seems, that I am missing something.

1. I also tried to use vue-plugin-load-script but it gives me the same error
2. I am not using `checkout.js`, which seems not supported anymore by paypal

if I add the `paypal.Buttons().render('.checkout')` function call inside `index.html` just below the paypal js script tag, it seems to work. But it would load the buttons only the first time the application is loaded. It also gives an error, if there is no div container with a "checkout" class found.

All research gives me either results for old and deprecated versions or does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the error was caused by eslint. after removing eslit it seems to work:

`npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint`

However I wonder, how to solve this problem, without removing eslint.